How to make iOS xxt automation script？
I want to make an automated control for iOS to register some accounts in batches, but I don’t know what technology to use. Android is easy to operate, but iOS doesn’t know how to operate it!
I tried using easyclick but it didn't work very well. When needed now: pc central control collects and distributes AWZ backup package, then installs awz after ios jailbreak, and cooperates with xxt framework to automatically register in batches
